# Реализация своего pop() для стека C++

Tags: c++, стек

```
// Online C++ Compiler - Build, Compile and Run your C++ programs online in your favorite browser


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace s21 {
    template <class T>
    class stack {
        public:
            using value_type = T;
            using reference = T&;
            using const_reference = const T&;
            using size_type = std::size_t;
        
        public:
            stack();
            ~stack();
            void push(const_reference value);
            const_reference top();
            void pop();

        private:
            T *array_;
            size_t size_;
            size_t capacity_;
    };
}



namespace s21 {
    template <class T> 
    stack<T>::stack() : array_(nullptr), size_(0), capacity_(0) {}

    template <class T> 
    stack<T>::~stack() {
        if (size_ != 1) {
            array_ -= size_ - 1;
           // delete [] array_;
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void stack<T>::push(const_reference value) {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            capacity_ = 10;
            array_ = new T[capacity_];
        } else {
            array_++;
        }
        if (size_ == capacity_) {
            capacity_ += 10;
            T *tmp = new T[capacity_];
            std::copy(array_, array_ + 10, tmp);
            delete [] array_;
            array_ = tmp;
        } 
        size_++;
        *array_ = value;
    }

    template <class T>
    typename stack<T>::const_reference stack<T>::top() {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw(std::out_of_range("Stack is empty"));
        }
        return *array_;
    }

    template <class T>
    void stack<T>::pop() {
        T *temp = array_;
        array_--;
        delete temp;
        size_--;
    }
}

int main() {
    s21::stack <int> steck_;
    steck_.push(1);
    steck_.push(2);
    steck_.push(3);
    steck_.push(4);
    steck_.pop();
    std::cout << steck_.top();
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу нормально удалить элемент с вершины стека. Получаю, что освобождаю память, которая не была выделена. Хотя делаю все 1 в 1 (вроде) по таким же вопросам из интернета.

Comment: Зачем вы удаляете массив?!! Еще и пытаетесь к нему прицепить `--`? Просто размер уменьшили, и больше ничего и не надо — только следить, чтоб не снимать с пустого стека...

Comment: удалять то зачем? вообще с указателями работа крайне странная.

Comment: Ну я хочу удалить не массив, а только самый последний его элемент. Удаляю, чтобы, допустим, сделаю я пару раз pop(), те элементы, вроде как, должны пропадать. Но если я сдвину опять указатель вперёд, эти элементы там все ещё останутся

Comment: Вы когда удаляете элемент, просто уменьшаете `size`. По-сути `size` - указатель на последний элемент в массиве (вершина стека). А когда добавляете - увеличиваете `size` и в это место записываете новый элемент. Вообще не трогайте указатель на выделенную память.

Comment: вы добавляете с кодом `array_++; size_++; *array_ = value;` Удаление должно быть обратным действием. `size_--;array_--;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe `array_` вообще трогать нельзя - это указатель на выделенную память. Его менять только при реаллокации буфера.

Comment: @DmitryK всё от алгоритма зависит. `p=new int[10];++p;++p;--p;--p;delete[]p;` пахать будет.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Это если в одной функции. А автор пишет контейнер, вызовы функций будут снаружи, и количество инкрементов и декрементов далеко не факт что совпадет. И после 10 инкрементов, начнется перевыделение памяти, которое должно будет удалить старый буфер и получится `p=new int[10];++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;++p;delete[]p;`

Comment: @DmitryK для экономии памяти и без третьего указателя можно просто знать, что начало массива здесь : `array_-size_`

Comment: @AlexGlebe согласен, можно. Но тогда при всех операциях нужно увеличивать/уменьшать и указатель и размер `++array_; ++size_;` и удалять `delete[] (array_-size_)`. Так сложнее писать и проще запутаться. А вообще фантазия программиста неограничима!

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в логике, приводящая к утечкам памяти. В `push()` вы проверяете `size`, хотя надо проверять только `capacity_`.

```
template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(const_reference value) 
{
    if (size_ == 0) 
    {
       capacity_ = 10;
       array_ = new T[capacity_];
    }
```

Смотрите, вначале у вас 0 элементов, при первом `push()` выделили память и у вас стало `capacity_ == 10; size_ == 1;`. Потом сделали `pop()` и стало `capacity_ == 10; size_ == 0;`. И при следующем `push()` вы перевыделяете память, не удалив старую.
Здесь нет ни одной функции без ошибок.
Выделение памяти под массив и удаление/добавление элементов - это два разных процесса. `T *array_;` - нужно изменять либо при первоначальном выделении памяти, либо когда памяти для хранения элементов уже не хватает. Во всех остальных случаях при добавлении элемента вы делаете `++size_;`, при удалении элемента - `--size_;` (не забывая проверить границы).

```
template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(const_reference value) 
{
    if (size_ == capacity_) 
    {
        capacity_ += 10;
        T *tmp = new T[capacity_];
        std::copy(array_, array_ + 10, tmp);
        delete[] array_;
        array_ = tmp;
    } 
    array_[size_] = value;
    ++size_;
}

template <class T>
typename stack<T>::const_reference stack<T>::top() 
{
   if (size_ == 0) 
       throw(std::out_of_range("Stack is empty"));
   return array_[size_ - 1];
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::pop() 
{
   if (size_ == 0) 
       throw(std::out_of_range("Stack is empty"));
   --size_;
}
```

Comment: Так ну вот тут же выходит, допустим, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 занесу в стек. Потом 4 раза сделаю поп. Через топ получу 1. Но при этом, будет возможность прописать array_[4] (ну где-то внутри функций класса) и вернётся 5. Или это нормально и так и должно быть?

Comment: Это нормально. Внутри класса это то, что пишете вы. Другим туда хода нет - они могут только вызывать `push() pop()` и т.д. А вы сами наверное это делать не будете же? Без особой необходимости? :)

Comment: Ещё у вас код не защищен от исключений. Почитайте про идиому RAII, замените `T *array_;` на `unique_ptr<T> array_`, в методе `push()` делайте `capacity_ += 10;` уже после выделения памяти.